# Conditional breakpoint using strcmp() in GDB on Mac OS X conflicts with Objective-C runtime

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, gdb

I'm trying to debug a program that I do not have the source for on Mac OS X. I would like to know what arguments it is calling [`gettattrlist()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getattrlist.2.html) with, and inspect the return value, for two different volumes (in order to compare and see why it will let you use one volume and not the other).

I first tried `dtruss`; but that's useless for `getattrlist()`; it shows only the pointers that are being passed into `getattrlist()` (and doesn't even know how many arguments `getattrlist()` takes).

```
  635/0x1dc5:  getattrlist("/Volumes/MyVolume\0", 0x113FA6380, 0x113FA5FD0)                 = 0 0
  635/0x1dc5:  getattrlist("/Volumes/MyVolume\0", 0x113FA4F00, 0x113FA4B30)                 = 0 0
  635/0x1dc5:  getattrlist("/Volumes/MyVolume\0", 0x113FA5870, 0x113FA54C0)                 = 0 0
  635/0x19c6:  getattrlist("/Volumes/MyVolume\0", 0x7FFF5FBF9140, 0x7FFF5FBF8D70)           = 0 0
  635/0x19c6:  getattrlist("/Volumes/MyVolume\0", 0x7FFF5FBFA8A0, 0x7FFF5FBFA4F0)           = 0 0
```

So I tried GDB. I can set an unconditional breakpoint on `getattrlist()`, and take a look at its first argument, but it's called way too often for that to be useful.

```
(gdb) break getattrlist
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7fff8e90b6ac
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007fff8e90b6ac in getattrlist ()
(gdb) p (char *)$rdi
$1 = 0x7fff5fbfd67e "/some/random/path"
```

So, I probably need a conditional breakpoint, that will break only when the first argument matches the path I'm interested in. That shouldn't be too hard, right?

```
(gdb) delete
Delete all breakpoints? (y or n) y
(gdb) break getattrlist if ((int)strcmp((char *)$rdi, "/Volumes/My Volume")) == 0
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7fff8e90b6ac
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Canceling call as the malloc lock is held so it isn't safe to call the runtime.
Issue the command:
    set objc-non-blocking-mode off 
to override this check if you are sure your call doesn't use the malloc libraries or the ObjC runtime.
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
Canceling call as the malloc lock is held so it isn't safe to call the runtime.
Issue the command:
    set objc-non-blocking-mode off 
to override this check if you are sure your call doesn't use the malloc libraries or the ObjC runtime.

Breakpoint 2, 0x00007fff8e90b6ac in getattrlist ()
(gdb) p (char *)$rdi
 $12 = 0x7fff5fbfd67e "/some/other/random/path"
```

What's this? GDB has ignored my condition because it suspects that it might call `malloc()` or the ObjC runtime? OK, well, `strcmp()` shouldn't call `malloc()`; it should just compare the strings byte by byte until it gets to a null character. So lets set that option the message recommends to override the check:

```
(gdb) set objc-non-blocking-mode off
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Segmentation fault: 11
```

No dice. GDB and the application both die.

Any suggestions on how to set a conditional watchpoint on a string from GDB without running into this issue? Or other ways of capturing the arguments and return values (which are stored via an output argument) of `getattrlist()`, that works better than `dtruss()`?

#### Edit

Tried matt's solution, but no luck:

```
(gdb) set $vol = (char *) malloc((int)strlen("/Volumes/My Volume") + 1)
(gdb) call (int)strcpy($vol, "/Volumes/My Volume")
$1 = 236411760
(gdb) break getattrlist if ((int)strcmp((char *)$rdi, $vol)) == 0
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7fff8e90b6ac
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Unsafe to run code: malloc zone lock is held for some zone..
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
Canceling call as the malloc lock is held so it isn't safe to call the runtime.
Issue the command:
    set objc-non-blocking-mode off 
to override this check if you are sure your call doesn't use the malloc libraries or the ObjC runtime.

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007fff8e90b6ac in getattrlist ()
(gdb) p (char *)$rdi
$4 = 0x11a715838 "/some/other/random/path"
```

I decided to try `memcmp()` instead of `strcmp()`; no luck there either:

```
(gdb) break getattrlist if ((int)memcmp((char *)$rdi, $vol, 18)) == 0
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7fff8e90b6ac
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Unsafe to run code: malloc zone lock is held for some zone..
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
Canceling call as the malloc lock is held so it isn't safe to call the runtime.
Issue the command:
    set objc-non-blocking-mode off 
to override this check if you are sure your call doesn't use the malloc libraries or the ObjC runtime.

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007fff8e90b6ac in getattrlist ()
(gdb)
```

At this point, I figured "OK, now there really shouldn't be anything using `malloc()`", so I decided to try `set objc-non-blocking-mode off` again. Still no luck:

```
(gdb) set objc-non-blocking-mode off
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Reading symbols for shared libraries ... done
Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
Reading symbols for shared libraries ....... done
[Switching to process 5456 thread 0x2971b]
[Switching to process 5456 thread 0x29e2f]
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
[Switching to process 5456 thread 0x29e2f]
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on"
Evaluation of the expression containing the function (memcmp) will be abandoned.

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on"
Evaluation of the expression containing the function (memcmp) will be abandoned.

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Hmm. What state am I in?

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000011e6ec070 in ?? ()
```

Ick. That doesn't look good. What if I continue here?

```
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
[Switching to process 5456 thread 0x2971b]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff8e90b6ac in getattrlist ()
#1  0x00007fff897c9c4b in GetPathVolFSAttributes ()
#2  0x00007fff897c9459 in PathGetObjectInfo ()
#3  0x00007fff897c9279 in FSPathMakeRefInternal ()
#4  0x00007fff8767b3ee in FSNodePrepareFSRef ()
... snip ...
(gdb) p (char *)$rdi
$2 = 0x10db1c2b0 "/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle"
```

Nope. Still not actually breaking on the correct call to `getattrlist()`; and everything has died in the meantime due to the null pointer dereference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that something like the following should work.

```
(gdb) start
...
(gdb) set $x = malloc(strlen("foobar") + 1)
(gdb) call strcpy($x, "foobar")
(gdb) break a_leg if strcmp(foo, $x) == 0
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but nope, doesn't work. I've updated my question with the details.

Comment: Ah! That, plus using `set objc-non-blocking-mode off`, seemed to do the trick, though I have no idea what state it has left the application in.

Comment: Ugh. Spoke too soon. Sorry for briefly accepting your answer; but the question does remain open.

Comment: @BrianCampbell np, I don't have a mac/mac gdb so hard to attempt, if you want to give a recent FSF gdb a try, there is the new $_streq() convenience function http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Funs.html, good luck finding a solution (otherwise maybe the ever ugly ((char *)$rdi)[0] == '/' && ...

Comment: I don't believe that FSF gdb works on Mac OS X; Apple has changed too much. The `((char *)$rdi[0]` approach does work, however; and actually, I can take a bit of a shortcut and just look at a few unique characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of GDB:

```
(gdb) start
(gdb) break a_leg if $_streq(foo, "foobar")
```

I'm not sure in what version this was introduced, but it's at least present in 7.7.1.

Comment: and to prevent unnecessary errors with e.g. rdi register,, `break position if $_streq((char*)$rdi, "foobar")`